# armeabi-v7a compiling error for cpp file

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I am using getline function and compiling using ndk but i am getting error :

```
'getline' was not declared in this scope
```

is this error due to limitations of armeabi-v7a or due to glib?How can it be resolved for the same function.

```
I have already #define _GNU_SOURCE before <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you encounter such an error, you go to your NDK directory and user either Midnight Commander (Linux) or Far Manager (Windows, Linux+Wine) to search the files (file mask: `*.h`) for your function, `getline` in this case. You will get a screenful of search results, and it's up to you to *#include* the right file.

Once in a while your function will not be found; in this case you search the 'net for a place where you can borrow the source.

Sometimes the function in the code being ported has just no meaning, e.g. if the function reads a line from `stdin` but the program going to invoke it *is not a command-line utility*, there is a problem.

Most likely, the source that you port *#define*-s switches for Linux, Mac (Darwin) and Windows, you have to choose the right configuration to derive the Android configuration from (and probably the Mac one will be the best).